# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" cakephp

Tags: angularjs, cakephp-3

Bom dia pessoal

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com angular e cakePHP.
Estou tentando fazer uma requisição para o backend e a seguinte mensagem aparece no console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8765/api/v1/users/client.json?client_id=cliente&client_secret=segredo. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

meu controller

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $location) {

$scope.fazerLogin = function(usuario){
    //console.log(usuario);
    //http://localhost:8765/api/v1/users/client.json?client_id=cliente&client_secret=segredo"
    var url = "";
    var cid = "cliente";
    var cs = "segredo";
    $http.post("http://localhost:8765/api/v1/users/client.json?client_id="+cid+"&client_secret="+cs).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

}


}])
```

meu php

```
<?php
public function beforeFilter()
{

   parent::beforeFilter();
           $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
           $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*');
           $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','X-Requested-With');
           $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, x-xsrf-token');
           $this->response->header('Access-Control-Max-Age','172800');
}
?>
```

Onde tenho que fazer o ajuste no meu php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá! 
O servidor não permite fazer requisições para outro domínio, além do atual. Deve-se dar permissão para isso, acrescentando o seguinte cabeçalho:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    ...
    ...
?>
```

Referência para mais detalhes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

No endpoint do seu serviço adicione:

```
$this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```