# Dificuldade em acessar url com angular post

Tags: angularjs, cakephp-3

Estou passando uma url e alguns dados via post do angular... Porém, o seguite aviso aparecem no console do chrome:

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Segue me código código do angular:

```
$http.post("localhost:8765/api/v1/users/oauth.json?token="+t1+"&redirect_url=localhost:8765/api/v1/users", data).success(function(responde){
            console.log(responde);
        });
```

O que significa esse aviso?

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing ;)

Comment: Cara, já coloquei essa linha, nos meus arquivos php.
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
Mas não adiantou.

Comment: Possível duplicata de ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" cakephp](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184839/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-cakephp)

Comment: @Sorack, o post anterior, que você colocou como referência, acima, já foi solucionado... Porém, estou fazendo uma requisição para outra url, com token, email e senha...

Answer (score 1):

Você está provavelmente executando este arquivo sem um servidor local usando o protocolo `file:\\`.

Adicionalmente, no trecho:

```
$http.post("localhost:8765/api/v1/[...]
```

O Angular está tentando inferir o protocolo baseado na sua chamada de referência, o que se traduz como:

```
$http.post("file:\\localhost:8765/api/v1/"[...]
```

Como se pode deduzir a partir da mensagem de erro, `file:\\` não é um protocolo suportado para CORS.

Para resolver o problema sirva a página de referência via um servidor web local.

Comment: Verdade, quando fui responder [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184839/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-cakephp) não levei isso em consideração. Muito bom!

Comment: Já alterei para "HTTP://localhost:8765/api/v1/users/...".
Eu não estou usando file:\\

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @GustavoSevero no caso ele se refere ao seu `client`. Qual o endereço na barra superior do seu navegador?

Comment: Este HTTP://localhost:8080/weset/www/#/login

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma regra que é uma página do dominio 'a.com.br' não pode fazer requisições no domínio 'b.com.br' esta é basicamente uma regra de segurança para evitar a utilização dos serviços exclusivos de uma aplicação em outro local.

Suponho que você tenha 2 servidores um para o projeto angular *(com os arquivos html, js, css...) e outro do backend (no caso o php)

Neste caso o servidor php tem que estar configurado para habilitar o cross orign.

Achei este link que pode te ajudar https://enable-cors.org/server.html

No php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

*(muito cuidado ao usar header no php)

Comment: Essa linha:header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); tenho que colocar em TODOS os arquivos do PHP?

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Eu colocaria no 1° arquivo a ser carregado pelo sistema, *(não conheço exatamente o cake) mas normalmente é um index.php que instancia o framework e dá o "run()"